# How can I debug a Launchd script that doesn't run on startup?

Tags: macos, launchd

I have some **launchd** scripts from *Homebrew*.  However I have to manually run them when I restart my computer:

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.mysql.mysqld</string>
  <key>Program</key>
  <string>/Users/dash/.local/Cellar/mysql/5.1.49/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>UserName</key>
  <string>dash</string>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/Users/dash/.local/var</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I thought this should happen on startup.  What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think this will have any effect (hence, I'm not making it an answer), but try running it without the "-w" flag for a test (i.e. "launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysqld.plist") and then restart. Or, maybe try the full file path to the plist (e.g. /Users/{you}/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysqld.plist). Just guessing here.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I'm sure that [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl) will tell you why.

Comment: Check out my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15820488/711807) to a similar issue.

Answer (score 47):

Best way I found to debug, in your plist:

```
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/tmp/mycommand.err</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/tmp/mycommand.out</string>
```

Open Console app, in "All Messages" you should see entries when your app fails or succeeds. Like this:

```
4/28/15 10:43:19.938 AM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (mycommand[18704]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
```

The issue I had was with ProgramArguments takes each item of command as `<string>` item in the array.

EDIT:
In my case, generating a simple wrapper for shell script worked even better.
This script sets up basic folder structure to make a shell script into an OS X "app" - https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/674099. This might work better for your `mysql -u arg1` command.

Answer (score 7):

For me, other solutions so far do not help me. My problem is kinda hard to debug, because the plist file is correct, the script is running fine alone in a terminal. Everything looks fine, but doesn't work.

I checked the log file by executing

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log
```

And then by unloading and loading the service again with the commands:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/example.plist
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/example.plist
```

I found an error message from the log file:

```
Program specified by service is not a Mach-O executable file.
```

What does it really mean? I didn't google. But, I feel it's because I didn't add `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the shell script. Because I am lazy to add this line sometimes.

After adding the heading, everything works fine.

Answer (score 4):

From OSX Yosemite 10.10 Onwards `launchctl` commands are changed.

Following commands will be required to start service automatically at the `reboot`.

```
sudo launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/${YOUR_SERVICE_NAME}.plist
sudo launchctl enable system/${YOUR_SERVICE_NAME}
sudo launchctl kickstart -kp system/${YOUR_SERVICE_NAME}
```

Note: It will launch service with user root and start system-wide.

References:
Launchctl Man Page(https://ss64.com/osx/launchctl.html)

Answer (score 2):

The start command expects the job **Label** as it's argument, so you would start it using the following...

```
launchctl start com.myfile.hostname.plist
```

To stop, simply do the following...

```
launchctl stop com.myfile.hostname.plist
```

Once all your testing is complete you would log out then in to load it or if your plist file is in the users Library folder type the following...

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.myfile.hostname.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility: Look in the directory:

```
/private/var/db/launchd.db/
```

and fine the "com.apple.launchd.peruser.###" file for your user. Open that and see if there is a entry like:

```
<key>com.mysql.mysqld.plist</key>
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

If so, try setting it to `<false/>`. Another file to look in for the same thing is:

```
/private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist
```

Comment: That looked promising, but alas it was `<false/>`

Comment: Maybe try cutting it out all together? I don't see how that would make any difference, but I'm grasping at straws.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming it. Change the filename to:

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysqld2.plist
```

and the Label section in the plist to:

```
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.mysql.mysqld2</string>
```

If you save a backup copy, make sure to move it outside of your ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ directory.

Finally, instead of using launchctl to load it, just logout and log back in. That will let launchd pick it up from your "LaunchAgents" directory by itself and take one more variable (i.e. launchctl) out of the mix.