# Bash Script Runs From Command Line But Not With Launchd

Tags: bash, ssh, osx-mavericks, launchd, autossh

I'm running autossh on a 2010 MBA running Mavericks. The script runs fine and works as expected from the command line, but not when run by launchd.

I have tried including PATH in the launchd plist, but that didn't help.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

/opt/local/bin/autossh -M 0 -f -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -o "ExitOnForwardFailure yes" -R 19990:localhost:22 mnewman@super.myddns.rocks -p 10000
```

I've tried with and without "ExitOnForwardFailure yes"

Here's the plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PATH</key>
        <string>/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
</string>
    </dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mgnewman.autossh</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/mnewman/bin/autossh.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've tried with and without the PATH key.

I want to be able to log in to this machine remotely. I have also tried this using just ssh and it runs fine from the command line and from launchd:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -NTC -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -R 19999:172.16.0.56:22 mnewman@super.myddns.rocks -p 10000
```

Of course, since ssh works I don't actually need autossh, but I would like to know why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have you tried to debug? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337513/how-can-i-debug-a-launchd-script-that-doesnt-run-on-startup

Comment: I've set the StandardErrorPath and StandardOutPath, but there's nothing there. I've also set debug to true, but the only thing in the system.log is:

Comment: I've set the StandardErrorPath and StandardOutPath, but there's nothing there. I've also set debug to true, but the only thing in the system.log is: 

`Jul  6 06:27:27 Axe com.apple.launchd.peruser.504[173] (com.mgnewman.autossh): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds`

I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

Working now. Turns out to get it to work with launchd I had to add two parameters to the shell script: "-f" to run in the background and "-N" execute no command. I have no idea why this worked.

```
#!/bin/bash

/opt/local/bin/autossh -f -M 0 -N -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -R 19990:localhost:22 mnewman@ksuper.myddns.rocks -p 10000
```